# HDMI 1.4 and 2560x1080

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi, resolution

I'm thinking about buying external monitor (LG 29UM59-P) which will be used with my laptop. The only problem I have is it's 21:9 ratio. My laptop is Lenovo v310-15 with build-in Intel HD Graphics 520 (native resolution is 1920x1080) and HDMI 1.4. Specification says that it can handle up to 4k@24Hz. The LG monitor native resolution is 2560x1080.
I have read that HDMI 1.4 officially doesn't support 21:9 ratio and it can be done only with HDMI >= 2.0.
Please look at the LG monitor site http://www.lg.com/sa_en/monitors/lg-29UM59-P It has only 2 HDMI inputs but the are HDMI 1.4. Now my question is. Will my laptop work with this monitor and this resolution (2560x1080, maybe not in 75Hz, but about 60)?

P.S I'm using Xubuntu OS if it matters (I don't think so)

Comment: @Ramhound Didn't they state "2560x1080"?

Comment: @Moab They also mention 4K at 24 Hz.  It wasn’t sure if they wanted 2K or 4K at 60 Hz.  It was unclear to me.

Comment: Sorry it could be misleading